# No output file created when compiled with gcc

Tags: java, bash, gcc, compilation, cygwin

Calling gcc compiler in a Java Source to compile a C file.

```
  List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
  String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");
  command.add("C:\\cygwin" + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh");
  command.add("-c");
  command.add("/usr/bin/gcc /cygdrive/d/WorkSpace/TEST/HelloWorld.c -o /cygdrive/d/WorkSpace/HHH");
  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
  final Process process = builder.start();
```

HHH.exe is not created. Can somebody explain me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Redirect the output to a Stream and try printing it.
OutputStream stream = process.getOutputStream();
use the stream to read what actually happens.

Comment: I did. I used process.getInputStream() to write the output to the console. But nothing appears.

Comment: Execute the command first and see. check whether, even direct execution shows nothing in the shell.

Comment: Do you later call `process.waitFor()`? Perhaps your Java app exists before `gcc` can do its job, thus killing it.

Comment: Direct execution of command in the cell successfully outputs HHH.exe.... calling process.waitFor() also didn't do any change.

Comment: Also puting -c before the .c file gives an output HHH file which is not executable format.

Comment: Hmm... putting the -c before will cause gcc to compile to a .o file
If you do process.waitFor() and then System.out.println(process.exitValue()) does it return 0 (indicating success)  Also, try looking at getErrorStream

Comment: printing process.exitValue() prints 0. getErrorStream also does not return anything

Comment: Compiling & running the same program from Command prompt gives the correct results. But When I am trying this from Eclipse it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the strings "cmd" and "/c" the first two elements in the command list.  This is necessary when invoking any command line process from Java.